# VBA code to run applications on all worksheets with name changing in runtime

Tags: vba, excel

here is the project explorer showing all the worksheets. worksheet1-19 are original sheets and worksheets 19-37 are those that i added.

I tried to use code names but it shows run time error 424.

I am currently working on a workbook that opens files from the same folder and adds to a specific workbook (that already has 19 worksheets in it)

Now after opening the files and adding this into the workbook, i want to run an application (that i recorded) to the new worksheets that was added into the workbook.

Problem is that the recorded application remembers the worksheet name of the previous worksheets i added. This means, when i add new worksheet to the workbook, the application does not run.

Can somebody help me on this? here is my (recorded) code to run the application:

```
Sub magic()
'
' magic Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Sheets("Result_MTY6015_2_4A_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("1").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY5915_2_3A_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("2").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY5015_2_5D_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("3").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY5015_2_4B_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("4").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY3415_3_1_1B_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("5").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY3415_2_6_1A_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("6").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY3115_2_1E_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("7").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY3115_2_1D_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("8").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY3015_3_2G_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("9").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY2615_3_2E_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("10").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY2615_3_2A_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("11").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY2515_2_5E_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("12").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY2315_2_5B_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("13").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY2215_3_3_1A_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("14").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY2015_2_6G_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("15").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY1615_3_3_1B_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("16").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY1415_3_1F_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("17").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("Result_MTY0315_2_7C_N").Select
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!filtercopy"
    Sheets("18").Range("A1").Paste

    Sheets("result").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets can be referenced by their [Worksheet.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx), [Worksheet.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) or [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) from the [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx).

Examples:

```
dim w as long
for w = 1 to worksheets.count
    with worksheets(w)
        'do something with each worksheet
    end with
next w

worksheets.add after:=worksheets(worksheets.count)
with worksheets(worksheets.count)
    'do something with the new last worksheet
end with

worksheets.add before:=worksheets(1)
with worksheets(1)
    'do something with the new first worksheet
end with

with worksheets("Sheet1")
    'do something with the worksheet named Sheet1 on the sheet tab in the application window
end with


with Sheet1
    'do something with the worksheet labeled Sheet1 in the Project Explorer
end with
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeeped. what i actually want to do now is this: loop tru 2nd until 19th tab, run application to autofilter then copy (which i have a code already) , then finally paste into worksheets with names "1", "2", "3", ...until "18". I dont know how to write a code that loops on the source worksheets (where i will copy data) then paste into specific worksheets, i.e. 2nd TAB worksheet will be copied into Sheet "1", 3rd TAB worksheet will copied into sheet "2" and so on until TAB 19th and sheet "18".